# matching keys of a hashmap to entries of a spark RDD in scala and adding value to if match found and writing rdd back to hbase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching, hbase

I am trying to read a HBase table using scala and then add a new column as tags based on the content in the rows in HBase Table. I have read the table as spark RDD. I also have a hashmap of which key value pairs are as follows:
keys are to be matched with the entries of spark rdd(generated from HBase table) and if match is found, the value from the hashmap is to be added into a new column.
The function to write to hbase table in the a new column name is this:

```
def convert (a:Int,s:String) : Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put]={
                        val p = new Put(a.toString.getBytes())
                        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("columnfamily"),Bytes.toBytes("col_2"), s.toString.getBytes())//a.toString.getBytes())
                        println("the value of a is: " + a)
                        new Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put](new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(a)), p);
                   }
 new PairRDDFunctions(newrddtohbaseLambda.map(x=>convert(x, ranjan))).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)
```

Then to read string from hashmap and compare and add back the code is this:

```
csvhashmap.keys.foreach{i=> if (arrayRDD.zipWithIndex.foreach{case(a,j) => a.split(" ").exists(i contains _); p = j.toInt}==true){new PairRDDFunctions(convert(p,csvhashmap(i))).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)}}
```

here csvhashmap is the above described hashmap, "words" is the rdd where we are trying to match the string. When the above command is run, I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put)
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(?, ?)]
```

How to get rid of it? I have tried many things to change the data type but each time I get some error. Also, I have checked for the individual functions inside the above snippet and they are just fine. When I integrate them together, I got the above error. Any help would be appreciated.